# Cannot access my user data

Tags: kubuntu, data-recovery, users, user-management, username

I forgot the username in which I had my data. When I went to user data management, this came.

[image: User Manager screenshot]

I remember the password but not username, so I don’t know how to log into that. I am new to Linux, I use Kubuntu 17.04. I didn't do anything by myself as I was afraid of deleting more data.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Your question has several issues. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question according to it. Especially, make your question title specific. Please also note the version 17.04 has passed [EOL](https://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life), so the question might be closed due to that. However, please add the output of the command `ls -l /home` using [edit] and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). Also note your current user. Do you use disk encryption?

Comment: " but not username" Open a terminal. The user name is shown when you do `ls -l /home/`

Comment: It looks like you have auto-login enabled. Open a terminal you see something like `username@hostname` where `username` is your username or type `whoami`. That will print out your username.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make my comment an answer.

It looks like you have auto-login enabled, which is good in that case ;-)

- Open a terminal (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- You now see something like `username@hostname` where `username` is your username
- If your prompt does not look like this for any reason (modified .bashrc, ...) type in the opened terminal `whoami`. This will print out your username.

If you want the username from a not logedin user:

- Open a terminal
- execute `ls /home/`. This will list the home directory, which has a folder for each user.

Comment: well am logined in different user , not the one in which i have my data

Comment: please see my edit. I added the command from @Melebius

Comment: @SahilSharma does not matter. Use the method I provided in the previous comment. all usernames, by default, have a /home/ with the username.